# TypeError when using MoviePy

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeerror, moviepy

In trying to learn a little about MoviePy, I copied some sample code (which I modified slightly) that cuts a 10 second section out of a movie file, overlays text on it, and writes it as a different file. The code works perfectly...only for certain files. I have two video files that I wanted to use the code on (just for practice). Both are .mov files, both are on the same drive and both of the paths are correct (I have verified them multiple times). The problem is I'm getting a TypeError on one of the files while it works perfectly on the other. Here's the code:

```
from moviepy.editor import *

x = int(input("When do you want the cut to start? "))
y = int(input("When do you want the cut to end? "))


video = VideoFileClip("D:\Videos\Gatlinburgh Drone River 2.MOV").subclip(x,y)

##video = VideoFileClip("D:\SF_ep\T_R_D.mov").subclip(x,y)  #Path is correct


txt_clip = ( TextClip("The Red Dot episode",fontsize=70,color='white')
             .set_position('center')
             .set_duration(10) )

result = CompositeVideoClip([video, txt_clip])

result.write_videofile("Text on Screen.webm",fps=25)
```

The above example works perfectly. However, when I comment it out and uncomment the video right below it, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Sam\Python Projects\MoviePy\Example3c.py", line 15, in <module>
    video = VideoFileClip("D:\\Seinfeld_All_Episodes\\The_Red_Dot.mov").subclip(x,y)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\moviepy\video\io\VideoFileClip.py", line 82, in __init__
    nbytes = audio_nbytes)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\moviepy\audio\io\AudioFileClip.py", line 63, in __init__
    buffersize=buffersize)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\moviepy\audio\io\readers.py", line 70, in __init__
    self.buffer_around(1)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\moviepy\audio\io\readers.py", line 234, in buffer_around
    self.buffer =  self.read_chunk(self.buffersize)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\moviepy\audio\io\readers.py", line 123, in read_chunk
    self.nchannels))
TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

I'm not changing any code, I'm just pointing to a different file.  I've tried the same with different files and gotten the same error. Why would it work on one and not the other? Any thoughts?

A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35204668/typeerror-using-moviepy) has been asked Stack Overflow before but there weren't any solid answers (at least none that applied to my particular situation).

Any help would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After searching around a bit more, I found a solution [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/moviepy/comments/44g28x/problem_trying_to_create_a_audiofileclip_object/). Line 122 of code in Readers.py was returning a float instead of an integer because it was using a single "/" instead of the double "//". I changed that line and it seems to have solved the problem. Details are at the link.

For the record, I still don't understand why it happened on certain files and not others. Nevertheless, the fix was simple.